# Is there a JavaScript bookmarklet to change a CSS-styled table into a <table>

Tags: css, html-table, bookmarklet

I need to copy a data display which is using CSS to create a table-like view for use in a word processor. The word processor, however, doesn't recognize adjacent 'cells' and messes up the layout. I want a bookmarklet to convert `<div>`s into semantic `<tr>`–`<th>`–`<td>` combos on the fly.

Example source html:

```
<div class="row review-row">
    <div class="col-6 review-label">old or new?</div>
    <div class="col-4">new</div>
</div>
<div class="row review-row">
    <div class="col-6 review-label">id?</div>
    <div class="col-s4">16</div>
</div>
<div class="row review-row">
    <div class="col-6 review-label">why do you cancel?</div>
    <div class="col-4">because</div>
</div>
<div class="row review-row">
    <div class="col-6 review-label">why bother</div>
    <div class="col-4">i have to :(</div>
</div>
```

The HTML I want the bookmarklet to generate:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>old or new?</th>
    <td>new</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>id?</th>
    <td>16</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>why do you cancel?</th>
    <td>because</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>why bother</th>
    <td>i have to :(</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: _“Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.”_ - https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score -1):

I've tackeled it with a Greasemonkey-script instead. This walks through each of the subsequent div's.

As I've prepared it for a specfic 'table' layout, so not being generic, I don't think its useful to share the script.